# event inside function not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have this code that defines a drawScene0 function which is supposed to interact with the user, responding to mouse clicks and keyboard but it doesn't seem to do it it just draws and when i try click or type, it does't work. I tried debugging the events loop inside the drawscene function as well as the main while loop, what i found was that the events loop inside the main while loop seemed way way quicker and responded perfectly, on the other hand he event loop inside the drawscene function was much slower in comparison and sometimes not even responding to clicks one in like ten clicks was being printed and even that one click was not doing what its supposed to do i'm really confused. Please help. Thank you!
I posted the full code for maximum understanding please don't mind the messed up code.
Here is the code:

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()

#       MAIN DISPLAY

displayHeight = 400
displayWidth = 400
programDisplay = pg.display.set_mode((displayHeight, displayWidth))
pg.display.set_caption('Scene0Prep')
#       TRANSPARENT SCREEN

s = pg.Surface((displayHeight, displayWidth), pg.SRCALPHA)

#       VARIABLES

currentScene = None

clock = pg.time.Clock()

font = pg.font.SysFont("PierSansLight", 20)

#       VARIABLES SECTION ENDS

#       DEFINE FUNCTIONS HERE

def drawScene_0 () :
    currentScene = 0
    #   Variables
    input_box = pg.Rect(150, 150, 100, 100)
    inactiveColor = pg.Color(105, 105, 105)
    activeColor = pg.Color(185, 185, 185)
    color = inactiveColor
    active = False
    inputTextN = ''
    #   Variables end

    def display_message (msg, xPos, yPos, color) :
        textS = font.render(msg, True, color)
        programDisplay.blit(textS, [xPos, yPos])

    def draw_bg () :
        rectNo = 0
        pg.draw.rect(s, (0, 0, 0, 100), [0, 0, 400, 400])
        while rectNo < 30 :
            boxWHi = (rectNo + 1) * 10
            boxHf = displayHeight - boxWHi
            boxWf = displayWidth - boxWHi
            boxXY = (rectNo + 1) * 5
            pg.draw.rect(s, (0, 0, 0, 100 +(rectNo*3.5)), [boxXY, boxXY, boxWf, boxHf])
            rectNo += 1

    # EVENTS
    for event in pg.event.get():
        '''click on box'''
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN :
            print('mouseDOWN')
            '''active or not'''
            if input_box.collidepoint(event.pos) :
                active = not active
                print(active)
            else :
                active = False
            '''changes color'''
            color = activeColor if active else inactiveColor
        '''done clicking'''
        '''now for typing action'''
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN :
            if active :
                '''when user hits enter'''
                if event.key == pg.K_RETURN :
                    # basically save the input text, in this case printing it up
                    print (inputTextN)
                    # empty the text
                    inputTextN = ''
                elif event.key == pg.K_BACKSPACE:
                    '''when user hits backspace delete one'''
                    inputTextN = inputTextN[:-1]
                elif len(inputTextN) < 4 :
                    '''typing'''
                    inputTextN += events.unicode
    # DONE EVENTS

    draw_bg()
    txt = font.render(inputTextN, True, (0, 0, 0))
    programDisplay.blit(txt, (input_box.x + 33, input_box.y + 35))
    pg.draw.rect (programDisplay, color, input_box, 2)
    display_message("Please Enter Your Name Below", 60, 40, (0, 0, 0))
    return inputTextN

#   drawScene_0 ENDS

#       FUNCTION SECTION ENDS

done = False

while not done:
    #       EVENT HANDLING HERE

    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True

    #       FILL THE SCREENS
    programDisplay.fill ((255, 255, 255))
    s.fill((255, 255, 255, 0))

    #       EVENTS END

    #       CODE GOES HERE!
    drawScene_0 ()


    #       BLIT AND UPDATE SCREEN + FPS

    programDisplay.blit(s, (0, 0))
    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)

pg.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: You should only handle events in one location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rearranged your code to handle events in one location. I've made minimal changes, but you should consider reviewing the [Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to improve your code readability. The code seems to be working as desired, let us know if you have any questions.

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()
#       MAIN DISPLAY
displayHeight = 400
displayWidth = 400
programDisplay = pg.display.set_mode((displayHeight, displayWidth))
pg.display.set_caption('Scene0Prep')
#       TRANSPARENT SCREEN
s = pg.Surface((displayHeight, displayWidth), pg.SRCALPHA)

#       VARIABLES
currentScene = None
clock = pg.time.Clock()
font = pg.font.SysFont("PierSansLight", 20)
#       VARIABLES SECTION ENDS

#       DEFINE FUNCTIONS HERE
def draw_bg () :
    rectNo = 0
    pg.draw.rect(s, (0, 0, 0, 100), [0, 0, 400, 400])
    while rectNo < 30 :
        boxWHi = (rectNo + 1) * 10
        boxHf = displayHeight - boxWHi
        boxWf = displayWidth - boxWHi
        boxXY = (rectNo + 1) * 5
        pg.draw.rect(s, (0, 0, 0, 100 +(rectNo*3.5)), [boxXY, boxXY, boxWf, boxHf])
        rectNo += 1

def display_message (msg, xPos, yPos, color) :
    textS = font.render(msg, True, color)
    programDisplay.blit(textS, [xPos, yPos])

def drawScene_0 () :
    draw_bg()
    txt = font.render(inputTextN, True, (0, 0, 0))
    programDisplay.blit(txt, (input_box.x + 33, input_box.y + 35))
    pg.draw.rect (programDisplay, color, input_box, 2)
    display_message("Please Enter Your Name Below", 60, 40, (0, 0, 0))

#       FUNCTION SECTION ENDS
done = False

currentScene = 0
#   Variables
input_box = pg.Rect(150, 150, 100, 100)
inactiveColor = pg.Color(105, 105, 105)
activeColor = pg.Color(185, 185, 185)
color = inactiveColor
active = False
inputTextN = ''

while not done:
    #       EVENT HANDLING HERE
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN :
            print('mouseDOWN')
            '''active or not'''
            if input_box.collidepoint(event.pos) :
                active = not active
                print(active)
            else :
                active = False
            '''changes color'''
            color = activeColor if active else inactiveColor
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN :
            if active :
                '''when user hits enter'''
                if event.key == pg.K_RETURN :
                    # basically save the input text, in this case printing it up
                    print (inputTextN)
                    # empty the text
                    inputTextN = ''
                elif event.key == pg.K_BACKSPACE:
                    '''when user hits backspace delete one'''
                    inputTextN = inputTextN[:-1]
                elif len(inputTextN) < 4 :
                    '''typing'''
                    inputTextN += event.unicode

    #       FILL THE SCREENS
    programDisplay.fill ((255, 255, 255))
    s.fill((255, 255, 255, 0))
    #       EVENTS END
    #       CODE GOES HERE!
    drawScene_0 ()
    #       BLIT AND UPDATE SCREEN + FPS
    programDisplay.blit(s, (0, 0))
    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)

pg.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: thank you so much really appreciate it thank you it worked =D